# How do I add (sql) database to my sintra application?

Tags: sql, ruby, sinatra

When I started to code my sinatra application I never used it before. Note that I had and still have no experience with RoR. I had one .rb file and one .haml and was happy. Now I had to split .rb file into about 10 'library' files as the whole application gets more and more complex.

I store some application logs/info in csv files and now I am getting conflicts when accessing the csv file. So I think that I need to introduce "proper" database solution. I want it to be part of my ruby (sinatra) application.

How can I introduce 'light' sql database into my sintra application?

---

I am on ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [i386-mingw32] soon upgrading to 1.9 (hopefully)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend looking at [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/). It's very flexible and powerful, and works well with SQLite, MySQL, Postgres, Oracle and other DBMs. It's not opinionated about how you talk to the database; You can use it as an ORM or with simple datasets, and allows embedded SQL or more programmatic approaches.

Comment: I thought there would be a (sql) database powered by ruby or that is not a good thought? I thought I would be able to have all in one package.

Comment: ? A database written in Ruby? Why? Use the tools that have proven themselves and don't reinvent wheels. The ORM layer makes it very easy to work with DBMs of all sorts and allow you to switch as your code and needs demand, without a rewrite, if you write your code intelligently.

Answer (score 1):

For ORM, both ActiveRecord and Sequel are recommended. About database, I guess sqlite3 will be good enough for your need. Also you can choose mysql or pg.

If you want to use active_record, you'll find this [article](http://blog.aizatto.com/2007/05/21/activerecord-without-rails/) very useful.
And if Sequel is the choice, just read Sequel documents [here](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/documentation.html).

After the gems installed. You can start writing some code to connect the db. Then maybe some migration task to build database tables (and don't forget build some corresponding models). Both gem have similar syntax for migrations. After that, import your csv data and well done.

Answer (score 0):

I have had no trouble using either `Active Record` or `DataMapper` to add object persistence to my `Sinatra` apps. People also tell me `Sequel` is very good but philosophically it is not not worlds apart from `Active Record` imho.

`Active Record` and `Sequel` favour a more *database-centric* approach, whereby you spell out your tables as a set of database and table definitions in a collection of migration files and merge them into a schema which is then used to build or update your database tables. If you really care about the underlying SQL database then one of these is for you. I find them to be six of one, a half-dozen the other.

`DataMapper` is more *object-centric* and lets you define the properties and object relationships you need in your object's own class definition; and then when your app launches you make sure you call `DataMapper.auto_upgrade!` and it upgrades the database to suit your object graph.  The upside is that you only have one place to look to find what properties your object might have. The downside is you have less control over the specifics of the underlying databases, though it's not impossible to tightly define the mappings, `DataMapper` works well when you care about object graphs over database tables.

The good news is they pretty much all work in the same way once you have your mappings from object graph to `SQL` database tables defined. All support lazy or pre-emptive loading of related collections of objects, many_to_many relationships, polymorphism, etc, and tend to vary only in configuration and seeding details.

I often start projects using `DataMapper` just for its speed of throwing up and tearing down database schemas, as the app's object graph is still in flux; I refactor quickly to use `Active Record` when the schema has settled down. Next project I think I'll give `Sequel` a go though, as people do seem to rave about it.

Comment: Sequel doesn't care whether you programmatically create your tables on the fly, or you can use migrations. The [example docs](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/files/README_rdoc.html) show that in the first couple lines.

Answer (score 0):

I have had success using datamapper with Sinatra, put like the other post you can also use Sequel and Active Record.  One advantage to maybe using Active Record though is if you do ever want to use/learn ROR, Active Record is the default ORM so that might be something that you want to consider.

If you don't want to go the ORM route you can always use the SQL-Ruby gem which will allow you to create and run sql queries.  Here is some example code from the website http://sqlite-ruby.rubyforge.org/

```
require 'sqlite'

db = SQLite::Database.new( "data.db" )

db.execute( "select * from table" ) do |row|
  p row
end

db.close
```